# Horizontal scrolling in desktop view in html/css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to scroll the content horizontally.

```
<div class="slider-section">
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="slide">1</div>
          <div class="slide">2</div>
          <div class="slide">3</div>
          <div class="slide">4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

css code:

```
.slider-section {
  max-width: 144rem;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.slider-section::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}

.slider {
  max-width: 24rem;
  height: 24rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 4.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24rem;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: green;
}
```

js:

```
const slide = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");

slide.forEach((el, i) => {
  console.log(el);
  el.style.transform = `translateX(${110 * (i - 1)}%)`;
});
```

However, the content is scrolling on mobile and tablet view but not on desktop view. I also want to scroll the content in the desktop view and I don't want to use any framework or library.I want to use only pure vanila javascript. I hope this can be done with the help of javascript.
you can check the code from [here](https://codepen.io/nasim67reja/pen/RwjOEGP)

Comment: It's only scrolling on mobile because on larger screens it has enough room to fit and therefore doesn't need to scroll. What do you mean when you say you want it to scroll on desktop?

Comment: yeah that's right. Suppose the content hasn't enough space to fit. `.slider {
  max-width: 54rem;
  height: 24rem;
} ` Then I want to scroll to horizontally in desktop view

Comment: It's working for me on desktop with the codepen you linked